# Ayuda con un trabajo para el colegio, no me detecta un "public class"

Tags: unity3d, unity

Como parte de un proyecto para la escuela estoy tratando de crear un juego tipo Idle/Clicker, (Con Unity) y estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta lo mas básico de programación, estoy estudiando y eso, pero como no he tenido mucho tiempo, pues estoy guiándome de [un video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTJyJvHZZ1I) de un tipo por internet.

Recién estoy empezando a crear el interfaz y los botones, pero me he atracado en algo fundamental y que seguramente sera muy simple de manera que tengo 2 Scripts uno para controlar el "oro" y uno para controlar las mejoras, con las que podrás ganar más oro.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Click {

    public UnityEngine.UI.Text goldDisplay;
    public int gold = 0;
    public int goldperclick = 1;

    void Update() {
        goldDisplay.text = "Gold: " + gold;
    }

    public void Clicked () {
        gold += goldperclick;
    }

}
```

No se porque salió así pero bueno, ese es el primer script

Y luego

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class UpgradeManager {
    public Click click;
}
```

Aquí no me detecta el "Click" cuando pongo `public`

Comment: pon la primera clase como static: **public static class Click**

Comment: O lo pones como static como te dice @juliocpiro o bien tendras que instanciar la clase para acceder a ella.

Comment: Imagino que el UpgradeManager va en un gameobject vacio con la clase Click.
Tengo varias preguntas, por que no heredan de MonoBehaviour ? Lo que quieres hacer es darle presionar un boton y lanzara una funcion para mejorar, si pulsas la pantalla entonces lanza la funcion Clicked(), esto es cierto ?

Answer (score 1):

Los Script C# creados en Unity3D deben heredar de Monobehaviour, para ser añadidos a un GameObject de la escena como un componente.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Click : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text goldDisplay;
    public int gold = 0;
    public int goldperclick = 1;

    void Update() {
        goldDisplay.text = "Gold: " + gold;
    }

    public void Clicked () {
        gold += goldperclick;
    }

}
```

Con esto podras utilizar Metodos como "Update".

y en el otro script seria algo como.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class UpgradeManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    Click click;

    Awake()
    {
      click = FindGameObjectWithType<Click>();
    }
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html